# is it possible not to pay $99 to create unsigned ipa so client can sign it?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS and trying to figure out is it necessary to enroll into iOS development program in case when I'm neither going to submit apps to AppStore nor test them on real devices (at least in the near future).

The only thing I need for now is to be able to send a build to my client who already has iOS Developer 
Account so he can sign it on his own and run it on real device or submit it to App Store.

Is it possible to do it without paying $99? Or every developer, even working for companies, have to pay to Apple?

What is really matters is that client has a way to install .ipa on his device to check the development progress and give a feedback while I'm not paying to Apple for this.

For the moment I have only free AppleId which I've added to Xcode. Will it be enough if the client with the iOS Developer Account to invite me to the team so I can choose one from Xcode Targets->Team to fix  'No matching signing identity found'?

**Edit**

Looks like my client has individual account not company and option with inviting to a team is not a case

Comment: You can send the source code and let him compile it and sign it?

Comment: If you're working for a company, the company pays $99 and adds you to its team. I can't answer as to whether you can persuade Xcode to build an unsigned iOS binary but, yes, in principle it can be [re]signed elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, have your client add you as a developer to their account.

Comment: I thought of option of sending sources to client. I'm just gathering information to provide him possible options

Comment: For the first part of your question. Sure. I did basically the same thing you are doing for the first six months of developing my apps. When I was ready to publish I got an account and tested on real devices.

Comment: @JScarry: you mean you sent sources to client during development period?

Comment: @Tommy Looks like it is answers both my question - if client has paid for the iOS Developer Account he can invite me to his team and I'll b able to use the relevant data to build ipa, right? It would be great to be able to provide ready-to-use ipa from my side so client don't have to cast over sources or 'unsigned' ipa

Comment: You could move all your implementation files to another project that compiles a static library, import that in the original project, along with the headers, and give that projects to the client, who can compile and sign it.

Comment: "you mean you sent sources to client during development period?" No. I set up a git repository on my server. I did most of the development work,  but since I had never coded in an object oriented language before, I would often get stuck. One of my guys synched his free developer account with the repository and would run the code to see what I was doing wrong. When I spent the $99 and ran the code on actual devices, his synched version continued to work on his free account. I don’t believe we ever tried to add him to the team, so I don’t know how that works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[summarizing the comments:]

If your client has a iOS Developer Account, they should invite you to their team as a developer. That way you will be able to:

- generate your own developer code signing certificate
- add your own device(s) to the team provisioning profile, and develop on-device
- use their App IDs and team ID, which is critical if the app uses entitlements at all

Once you have a build ready for them to submit, you can either:

- send them the whole project source code, which they can build, sign, and export as needed;
- archive, then in the organizer, "export as Xcode archive", and send them the result, which can be imported, signed, and re-exported/submitted by their copy of Xcode.

Comment: I'm afraid my client has individual account and he will not be able to invite a new members. Updating my question with this info

Comment: Ouch! You're going to have a rough ride then. Sending him the source code is probably your best bet, then, but you won't be able to develop on-device. He could convert to a team account by contacting Apple support, and it might be worth the trouble. see https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.php#companyassellername

Comment: thanks for suggestion! Looks like it can work. All the more as the pricing is the same for company and individual :)

Comment: And one more question: in case my client converts his account into company one and invites me in the team - will it be enough for creating release builds for him from my side in future so the client don't have to be involved in any technical details (like compiling sources, signing archives etc.)

Comment: Only the team agent can submit builds to the store, so for minimum client involvement, follow the .xcarchive workflow above. If that's too much, they could always give you the team agent password and let you deal with it... :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt one can sign an unsigned/compiled IPA, but one option is to request their developer/distribution certificate with its private key, along with the provisioning profile that matches the certificate. But that solution involves giving up a private key, which is not a best practice security-wise. Another option is to get involved into the team, which is only available for company or enterprise account, IIRC. If they are just individual accounts, that method wouldn't also work.

Comment: I think my client has individual account. Looks like you are right and in this case there is no option for me to be invited from his side. So there are two option left - pay or send sources so the client have to build and sign ipa every time on his own? Not sure that the latter is a good practice. May be there are other options?